# How to get build version without pakage?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to show what build version and number they are on my app. For example, "build version : 1.0.0".How would I be able to get the build version and number within flutter without using packages so I will have a clean code!

Comment: "without packages" doesn't not mean "clean code".  Avoiding packages means that you will have to reinvent the wheel all the time.

Comment: @jamesdlin You may true but we have not to use packages alot cus it have licences and may have bugs or other things. i will be happey if flutter embaded code that show version build in SDK.

Comment: All packages are open-source; you're free to review their code and contribute fixes if you find bugs.  For non-trivial things, it shouldn't be much worse than if you wrote it yourself.  The licensing issue is a legitimate problem, but you should first find a package that does what you want and *then* determine if it has an unacceptable license.  The Dart and Flutter SDKs themselves use BSD licenses, and most Dart packages also use BSD licenses (or use the similar MIT license).

Comment: @jamesdlin You right about using package that realy fit my needs ! I have a quation do you think I need a Pkg for getting only build version and number for my app ?